# Show this code if user has previously left a comment

Tags: conditional-content, comment-form

Below is my code which is inserted into the comment template, It should show the comment form, if the user has never posted a comment on a particular post.

Or if they have posted a comment on this particular post, they should see a star rating selection.

```
    <?php if ( 1 < wp_count_comments( get_the_ID() )->approved ) : ?>
<?php if(function_exists('the_ratings')) { the_ratings(); } ?>
     <?php else: ?>
    <?php comment_form(array('class_submit'=>'button')); ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

The problem is its showing the ratings all the time and hiding the comment form all of the time.

Is there a better way of accomplishing what I need ?

Comment: Where are you checking for the user has been port a comment on a particular post?

Comment: Ah from your comment I think I understand why its not working, does the above code only check whether there is comments on the post at all ? And doesnt check if that particular user has commented ?  If so whats the best way of adding the check for a particular user ?

Comment: Do you want to allow only one-time comment per user in a post?

Comment: Yes users will only be able to post 1 comment per post.  ( we are using the comment system as a review system)  So they can leave 1 review.  Although it would be nice for them to be able to reply to nested comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be the main code

```
 global $current_user, $post;
 $user_comment_count = get_comments(array('user_id' => $current_user->ID, 'post_id'=>$post->ID) );

if($user_comment_count) { 
   the_ratings(); 
} else {
    comment_form(array('class_submit'=>'button'));
}
```

Also you may want to first check is the user is logged in with the `is_user_logged_in()`